# NodeJs is not creating a database in MongoDb? How to solve it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

The follow code is a NodeJS 8.10 inside a lambda function using `mongodb drive`. It is part of this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp).

It should create a database `testlambda2` and return `"inside function"`. But I am getting only `"outside function"` and the database is not being created. It seems that function is not being called. That was the only way that I could figure out if the connection was established. What am I missing?

```
"use strict";

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function createDb(){
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://167.114.36.160:27017/testlambda2",
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
        function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Database created!");
            db.close();
            return "inside function";
    });
    return "outside function";
}


module.exports.consumo_monofasico = async (event, context) => {

    var res= await createDb();

    const promise = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                message: 'Test mongo!',
                resultado:res
            },
            null,
            2
        ),
    };
    return promise
};
```

I have no error in cloudwatch, and no error logs
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createDB` function will never return `"inside function"`, because the return line `return "inside function";` is return for `callback` function of `function (err, db)` not for `createDB`. Another side, `MongoClient.connect` and `return "outside function";` execute in "the same" time, then `createDB` will do nothing, it just get back `"outside function"` string. Your lambda function just takes 50ms :| .

But why, `MongoClient.connect` is a `callback` function, the `callback` function will be call when **task - MongoClient.connect** done, in your code you don't care about that, you just return `"outside function"` string ???

I see you use `await` keyword, I guest you want to wait until a connection to DB is already, then execute next operator. As you know (maybe) `await` only effect with a `Promise` (To many things to explain there, you can read more in the internet).

How to solve your problem, `MongoClient.connect` does not have `Promise` version (I think so), then you have to convert it to a Promise function version, and I think what you need to wait is a instance of DB instead of a string. Finally, my suggest is as follow:

```
"use strict";

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function createDb() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // return createDb a promise
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://167.114.36.160:27017/testlambda2",
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
      function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        };
        console.log("Database created!");
        resolve(db); // like return :)
      });
  })
}


module.exports.consumo_monofasico = async (event, context) => {
  let result = {};

  try {
    var db = await createDb(); // now you can get a response what has been "pushed" in  `resolve`
    // TODO: Do some things with db instance
    // success response
    result = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          message: 'Test mongo!',
          resultado: "Connected!"
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    };
    // close db connection
    db.close();
  } catch (err) { // err is a error what has been pushed in `reject` :|
    // error response
    result = {
      statusCode: 500, // http error code
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          message: 'Test mongo!',
          resultado: err
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    };
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mongo is a promise, however you're not marking it as an async function or returning the promise for evaluation so it's returning the outside function piece before it completes the mongo promise, and it runs the mongo stuff in the background because of how the asynchronous nature of javascript works.

```
"use strict";

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.consumo_monofasico = async (event, context) => {
    try {
       var db = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://167.114.36.160:27017/testlambda2", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
       console.log("Database created!");
       db.close();
    } catch (err) {
       console.log('db error');
       throw err;
    }
    const promise = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                message: 'Test mongo!',
                resultado:res
            },
            null,
            2
        ),
    };
    return promise
};
```